# jQgrid drag and drop from static to dynamic tables

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have two panels on a page. The left panel consists of one grid while the right is populated by dynamic grids. The dynamic controls are rendered on the server side (ASP .NET C#). I'm currently using jQgrid to load grids on the page, also for drag and drop of rows from the left panel grid to the right panel grids (see screenshot here: [Static grid on the left, dynamic grids on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Ewc.png)). I actually have a few problems:
1. On drop, row seems to make the 1st column (ID) disappear.
2. Allowing rows from the dynamic grids to be draggable back to the left panel grid made the dynamic grids lose the capability to sort within the grid.

Can someone help me please? I have tried to search for answers, but enlightenment seems to be still beyond my grasp. Thanks.